# why does my converted py to exe doesnt run?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I have this working py file that I wanted to convert into an executable file. I used pyinstaller to do this, to be specific I used this command

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon=images.ico file.py
```

Actually it created an executable file inside the dist folder. But when I run this executable an error occurs that shows 'failed to execute script' or sometimes nothing happens. How can I successfully convert and run it

Note: the py file contains pyqt5 and pandas module. Below is the py file.

```
import os, sys  
import pandas as pd  
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QLabel,QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout,QPushButton, QMessageBox from PyQt5 
import QtGui, QtCore from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Edit CSV'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

        self.setFixedSize(400, 650)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('images.png'))

        label_input = QLabel("Enter the filename of CSV that you want edit:")
        label_input.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 18))
        self.input = QLineEdit(self)
        self.input.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 18))
        self.input.setMaximumWidth(350)

        labelImage = QLabel(self)
        self.pixmap = QPixmap("stn.png")
        labelImage.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

        label_output = QLabel("Enter the desired output filename of CSV")
        label_output.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 18))
        self.output = QLineEdit(self)
        self.output.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 18))
        self.output.setMaximumWidth(350)

        but_edit = QPushButton("edit", self)
        but_edit.setMaximumWidth(60)
        but_edit.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Times", 18))

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layoutHpic = QHBoxLayout()
        layoutH = QHBoxLayout()

        layout.addWidget(label_input)
        layout.addWidget(self.input)
        layout.addStretch()

        layoutHpic.addStretch()
        layoutHpic.addWidget(labelImage)
        layoutHpic.addStretch()
        layout.addLayout(layoutHpic)
        layout.addStretch()

        layout.addWidget(label_output)
        layout.addWidget(self.output)

        layoutH.addStretch()
        layoutH.addWidget(but_edit)
        layoutH.addStretch()
        layout.addLayout(layoutH)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        def edit_csv():
            input_file = self.input.text().strip()
            output_file = self.output.text().strip()
            if input_file == "":
                QMessageBox.information(self, "Message", "Please choose a file!")
                return
            elif os.path.exists(input_file) == False:
                QMessageBox.about(self, "titt!", "File does not exist")
                return
            else:
                df = pd.read_csv(self.input.text())
                df = df.sort_values(["strLocal", "strTide"])
                df['strLocal'] = pd.to_datetime(df.strLocal)
                df['strLocal'] = df['strLocal'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
                df['strTide'] = df.strTide / 1000 * 0.1
                df[['Date','Time']] = df.strLocal.str.split(" ",expand=True)
                cols = df.columns.tolist()
                cols = cols[2:] + [cols[1]]
                df = df[cols]
                print(df)
                df.to_csv(output_file,index = False, header = False)
                QMessageBox.about(self, "titt!", "Done. " + output_file + " was created.")

        but_edit.clicked.connect(edit_csv)
        
    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.show()
     if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @ khelwood I've edited it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Please run the exe from the commandline and edit the full error message including stack traceback into your question.

Comment: Create a new environment, install pyinstaller, pandas, pyqt5 and other libraries you need.  Put `PyQt5` as hidden import and put `console = True` in your MySpec file. Generate and try to run your `.exe` and check what is the error if it doesn't work.

Comment: @DotDot remove `--onefile` option